# Searching for exact names and copy/paste info

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

As you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4aec.png) I have a spreadsheet with different words and codes.

Column A is missing the codes found in column E and I would like to populate column A with the codes found in column E.

Is there a way to do that using a formula, `if` statement, or VBA macro?

Comment: Yes. You can use `VLOOKUP`. But you will need your codes (column E) to go after your names (column F).

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
A2 = VLOOKUP(B2,$E$2:$F$10,2,FALSE)
```

Where:

- `B2` the name you want to get the code for
- `$E$2:$F$10` the range that holds your codes and names

Note:

- Your look up range **must** have the names in column E and codes in column F